# Better alternative to getting the 'inner html' of a div?

Tags: c#, html, regex, string, innerhtml

I have a string:

```
<div class="className1234"><p>Some html</p></div>
```

From this string, I would like to get `<p>Some html</p>` i.e. I would like to remove the surrounding div tags based on the fact that it's class contains 'className'.

**What I've Tried**

What I've tried works, but it's cludgey - and I know there'll be  a better alternative like regex or something. What I currently do is chain a series of `substring()`, `indexof()` and `replace()` calls to strip out the divs.

EDIT: I've used the phrase 'innerhtml' because I'd like to think there's a library out there somewhere that would allow me to manipulate a string with regard to the tags within it.

**PLEASE NOTE: There's no JQuery involved in this. It's all server-side C#.**
 (See tags)

Comment: No JQuery, all server-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(divStr);
// classAtr will be null if the root is not a div with a class with the value className1234
XmlNode classAtr = doc.SelectSingleNode("/div/@class[contains(., 'className1234')]");
string result = classAtr != null ? doc.DocumentElement.InnerXml : divStr;
```

Comment: This looks interesting. The XmlDocument could be the kind of class I referenced in my edit. Where have you stated that the div must be of a certain class name though? Thanks a lot. +1.

Comment: So you only want the inner contents if it's a certain class name?  What do you want to do when it's not that class? Retain the whole thing?

Comment: Literally only remove the first surrounding div tags if they contain a certain class name. If the first div tags do not contain the class name (or in fact the 'root' tags are <p> for example), leave it intact and don't alter the string at all. Thanks again.

Comment: @JLRishe: Not every valid HTML is valid XML. This code will only work reliably when the website has been developed using XHTML. For HTML5 exists no corresponding XHTML standard.

Comment: This is a NICE answer, thanks very much. I've learnt a lot just from reading your answer.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth That's a very good point, though I don't think that last statement is correct. [XHTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5#XHTML5) is alive and well.

Comment: JLRishe - can I please just confirm that this selector selects div classes that contain className and not equal to className? Thanks.

Comment: @DeeMac Updated my answer, however Daniel Hilgarth makes a good point.  If there's a risk your HTML contains markup that wouldn't be valid XML (such as unclosed <img > tags), you might be better off with the HtmlAgilityPack that others are suggesting.

Comment: Again, thanks a lot, much appreciated. Majority of people on stackoverflow seem to ask a lot of questions and not give much back, but you haven't asked a single question and still have 4k+ rep, well deserved.

Comment: @JLRishe: Indeed, I somehow missed that one completely.

Comment: It should be the other way: if, and only if, you are certain that your html is valid xml then this is a working solution, if not, then this is not a working solution. Something like Html Agility Pack is a more viable solution. You can do the same thing there, but you won't discover nasty bugs later due to "invalid" html (but it might be valid html, it's just not xml.)

Comment: @Onkelborg I think you'll find that's pretty much what I said.

Comment: @JLRishe No, you make it sound that the html may not be valid xml, but the truth is that html may be valid xml. Normally it's not true. You shouldn't expect html to be valid xml, it's most likely invalid xml. With that background I don't find your answer a good answer since it's a coincidence that it will work, and if it works right now, it creates an increased risk of introducing nasty bugs in the future.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), it's designed to allow operations on html documents, kind of like the builtin support for XML in the framework.

It might be overkill, but it will get the work done, easily, and you won't have to care about bad html

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you need to manipulate HTML, you should use a dedicated HTML parser/DOM library. One library I've found recommended here on StackOverflow for .Net is [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

As others said HtmlAgilityPack is the best for html parsing, also be sure to download HAP Explorer from HtmlAgilityPack site, use it to test your selects, anyway this SelectNode command will get :

```
  HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
  doc.Load(htmlFile);
  var myNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/div/@class[. = 'className1234']");
  foreach (HtmlNode node in myNodes)
  {
    // you code

  }
```